# Проверка и замена букв в переменной на цифры Python

Tags: python

Час добрый. Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом в python можно устроить проверку на наличие букв в переменной? На вход есть список из переменных основанных на любых цифрах, но в некоторых, в конце, будет присутствовать буква К. (200,14K,18112,1284K .......)

Как можно устроить проверку, есть ли в переменной наличие буквы и если она есть, то заменить ее на 000 ?

Нашел на просторах подобный код замены цифр на буквы, но как можно сделать подобное, но с проверкой и в случае обнаружения - заменой?

```
leettext = "Hell0 my name 1s J0hn"
leettext.translate(str.maketrans({"0":"o", "1":"i"}))
'Hello my name is John'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = ['200', '14K', '18112', '1284K']
l = [i.replace('K', '000') for i in l]
```

*`['200', '14000', '18112', '1284000']`*

Прохожусь по каждому элементу списка и заменяю K на 000